# Disable Facebook Like button for all authorized users

Tags: facebook, graph

Does anyone know a way to disable all "Like" buttons in Facebook problematically through one of their api's or otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: according to http://developers.facebook.com/policy/contact/ .. this is the go to place to find out answers to questions like this... even if the answer is, "any company who says they can do that is lying", that would at least give me something here...

Comment: This is clearly impossible....

Comment: you said: " I've seen a couple paid solutions out there that don't use browser plugins, or proxy servers, or anything like that" - can you point to where? Because I think this is not possible.

Comment: http://www.smarsh.com/social-media-archiving claim they can do this

Comment: Consider editing the question to add any more information you've gained. Or setting a bounty (except that you've got low rep).

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean hrmm... sure.. yeah, your right.. I do have low rep, and don't even know what a bounty is sir.

Comment: Bounties are explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). I've been able to set bounties on other people's questions, but I can't find the option on yours!

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean "Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty." http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: @wakuth - I looked at smarsh and was not able to find any reference to the like button. It seems they create a piec of software that acts as an intermediary to the comapany facebook presence, rather than giving employees actual access to the company official channels. Can you point to a specific citation?

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon I can't point out a specific citation on their site, but I do know that it's stated in the brochure they use. I actually called and just asked them how it worked from a customer perspective, and they said it effectively "hides" the like button so you can't see it at all. Maybe they're using a browser pack add in, and when Facebook.com loads, it hides the tag elements associated with the like buttons?